# Using a variable/ComboBox to search for a variable and then select a relevant Tab in a TabStrip

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

The setup is this:  I have a UserForm that is TabStrip for each of several service providing companies (Each company has select groups of individuals that receive a bill).  On the TabStrip is a ComboBox and 12 TextBox objects (one for each month of a year).  I have a defined global variable that gets passed between all my UserForms that is one of the groups receiving a bill.

My Goal:  I would like the ComboBox list be populated based on the currently selected Tab.  I also would like to, if possible, perform a search upon the Initialization of the UserForm for the current variable and match it against the ComboBox values.  If the variable is not located in the ComboBox it should cycle to the next Tab and perform the search again.  It should do this until the variable is located and then activate that Tab and select that value from the ComboBox.

This is a picture of my current UserForm setup. Hopefully it helps convey my intent a little better. [Userform Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMQMR.jpg)

Comment: 1) Where do we pick the data that will populate the combobox? 2) Is it a public variable? 3) Is it an array or a range or a string or something else? 4) Any other information about this variable? 5) This form will pop up with for a single company or the user will be able to select others tabstrip?

Comment: The ComboBox is populated from corresponding tables (named ranges) containing the customers pertaining to each billing company. The public variable is carried over from a selection on the previous UserForm and is intended to be used for dynamic objects throughout the entirety of the application.  To clarify, I have 4 worksheets each one with a table on it pertaining to each of the 4 Billing Companies(KDDI, NTT West, OTNet, Advanced Pay). The first column of each of the tables contains the individuals being billed by that company with subsequent columns containing months. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call PriSubPopulateCombobox
End Sub

Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()
    Call PriSubPopulateCombobox
End Sub

Private Sub PriSubPopulateCombobox()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCostumerList As Range
    Dim RngRangeTarget As Range
    Dim WksWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim CbxCombobox As ComboBox
    Dim TbsTabstrip As TabStrip
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set CbxCombobox = Me.ComboBox1
    Set TbsTabstrip = Me.TabStrip1
    
    'Setting WksWorksheet according to the value of TbsTabstrip.
    Select Case TbsTabstrip.Value
        Case Is = 0
            Set WksWorksheet = Worksheets("KDDI")
        Case Is = 1
            Set WksWorksheet = Worksheets("NTT West")
        Case Is = 2
            Set WksWorksheet = Worksheets("OT Net")
        Case Is = 3
            Set WksWorksheet = Worksheets("Advanced Pay")
    End Select
    
    'Setting RngCostumerList.
    With WksWorksheet
        Set RngCostumerList = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With
    
    'Clearing CbxCombobox.
    CbxCombobox.Clear
    
    'Filling CbxCombobox.
    For Each RngRangeTarget In RngCostumerList
        CbxCombobox.AddItem RngRangeTarget.Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Place it in the form module. Check if the variables are set properly and otherwise change them.

Report any question you have or bug you've eventually encountered. If it worked, please mark the answer as accepted.

***EDIT: selecting a tag before initializing.***

I came up with two ways to do it. Using a Select Case statement we have this solution:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    'Declaration.
    Dim StrCostumer As String
    
    'Setting the variable.
    StrCostumer = "Advanced Pay"
    
    'Activating the tab accordingly to StrCostumer.
    Select Case StrCostumer
        Case Is = "KDDI"
            Me.TabStrip1.Value = 0
        Case Is = "NTT West"
            Me.TabStrip1.Value = 1
        Case Is = "OT Net"
            Me.TabStrip1.Value = 2
        Case Is = "Advanced Pay"
            Me.TabStrip1.Value = 3
        Case Else
            MsgBox "No valid costumer found", vbCritical, "Error"
    End Select
    
    'Calling PriSubPopulateCombobox.
    Call PriSubPopulateCombobox
    
End Sub
```

Pro: it is quite strightfoward therefore easy to check. Con: it needs to be edited everytime there is a new entry.

The second solution checks every tab caption until it find the wanted costumer:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim StrCostumer As String
    Dim BytCostumer As Byte
    
    'Setting the variable.
    StrCostumer = "Advanced Pay"
    
    'If an error occurs during the searching, it will probably be cause by an overflow. _
    Whatever the reason, in such case the search is terminated.
    On Error GoTo CP_No_Tab_Found
    For BytCostumer = 0 To Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count
        'If the wanted costumer is found, the tab is selected.
        If Me.TabStrip1.Object(BytCostumer).Caption = StrCostumer Then
            Me.TabStrip1.Value = BytCostumer
            GoTo CP_Tab_Found
        End If
    Next
CP_No_Tab_Found:
    MsgBox "No valid costumer found", vbCritical, "Error"
CP_Tab_Found:
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Calling PriSubPopulateCombobox.
    Call PriSubPopulateCombobox
    
End Sub
```

Pro: it doesn't need to be edited for new entries. Con: it's a little more complicated to read.

In both cases you can set `StrCostumer` to match a public variable or a cell's value or whatever. In both cases if no tag matching `StrCostumer` is found, a critical message pops out and the form is showed anyway.

Comment: This is close.  It does part of what I was looking for but it doesn't seem like it's auto-selecting the Tab or Customer.  It is showing the appropriate customers in their respective Tabs.  What would I need to do to have it change to the correct Tab and Customer on load? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: On a previous UserForm I use a Find/Activate to locate and modify a cell's value.  Is that something that I can work into this code to do what I'm looking for? I'm not sure how to cycle through a table on one sheet and then look through a table on a separate sheet as well.  I apologize for the lack of clarity, I'm fairly new to VBA.

Comment: We can easily choose a tab strip page to be visualized when the form is initialized. Basically we just have to add to the private subroutine `UserForm_Initialize` a `Select case` statement (before it calls the `PriSubPopulateCombobox`). Depending on a certain condition, we will set a specific value for the tab strip. If you can't figure out how, just tell me how can i retrieve what page is to be selected on the tab strip; i'll modify the code for you so you'll have an example for future coding.

Comment: I will try and see what I can do on my own and then if I can't figure it out let you know.  Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: So I was able to get it to work but I couldn't get 'Select Case' to work. That would give me a Runtime Error type mismatch.  Instead I opted for 'If' 'Then' 'Else' which seems to be doing the trick. I am now working on trying to adjust the information displayed when selecting the customer while on a specific Tab, and being able to edit/update that information.  Thank you for the assistance up til now.

Comment: I've wrote down two solutions that should give you the form with the wanted tab selected. Posted them at the end of the answer. If the answer satisfies you, please mark as accepted (the v-shaped button on the left of the top-left corner of the answer).